# why can i not get responseText with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, go

i wanna do something like regist with ajax. i just use ajax request url "/check",and it returns "{success:1}",but when i use *res = request.responseText*, *res* is nothing.however,i console.log(request.responseText),it turns *{success:1}*,how can i get the value, what's wrong whith my code?

in my *regist.gtpl*

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"               "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>{{.Title}}</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    input {
        display: inline-block;
        background: rgba(45,45,45,.03);
    }
    form {
        text-align: center;
        width: 200px;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .container {
        margin-top: 120px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form method="post" action="/regist">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="账号"/>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="密码" />
        <button>sign me in</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/ajax.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">


    function cb(request){
      alert("Server is done!")
      console.log(request.responseText)
      var res = request.responseText
      //var resJSON = JSON.parse(res)
      //console.log(res)
      alert(res)
    }

    Get("http://127.0.0.1:3000/check",cb)

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

in my *main.go*

```
    func sayHelloName(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        r.ParseForm()
        fmt.Println(r.Form)
        for k, v := range r.Form {
            fmt.Println("key:", k)
            fmt.Println("value", v)
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "{userId:1}")
    }
    func Register(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        if r.Method == "GET" {
            fmt.Println("GET",r.URL.Path)
            t, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/regist.gtpl")

            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            //长度，容量
            //studentsandstates := make(studentsAndStateSlice,20)

            t.Execute(w, Render{Title:"注册"})
        }
    }

    func init() {
        staticHandler = http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("statics")))
    }

    func main() {
        http.HandleFunc("/check", sayHelloName)
        http.HandleFunc("/register", Register)
        //已经有静态文件了
        http.HandleFunc("/assets/", StaticServer)
        err := http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
        }
    }
```

in my *ajax.js*

```
var Get

(function(){var request = false

function createRequest() {

  try {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch (trymicrosoft) {
    //两种微软的XMLHttpRequest
    try {
      request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (othermicrosoft) {
      try {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (failed) {
        request = false;
      }
    }
  }
  if (!request)
    alert("Error initializing XMLHttpRequest!");
}

createRequest();

Get = function (url,cb){
    request.open("GET",url);
    request.onreadystatechange = cb(request);
    request.send();
}

})();
```

Comment: Are you serving the web page from the same server you're trying to access via XmlHTTPRequest?  If not, then the browser is probably treating it as a cross origin request and blocking the response.

Comment: yes,i got the regist page by get 127.0.0.1:3000/register

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in your `Get()` Javascript function:

```
Get = function (url,cb){
    request.open("GET",url);
    request.onreadystatechange = cb(request);
    request.send();
}
```

You are setting the `onreadystatechange` property to the result of calling `cb`.  At this point, the request has not been sent, so there is no response text to read.  Below is one possible way to solve the problem:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() { cb(request); };
```